# Is it better to have an Id as primary key or a double foreign key

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, data-analysis

I want to know what is the most optimized data structure:

I have 2 tables like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    Id Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Group
(
    Id Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nameOfGroup varchar(50)
)
```

In my table to connect persons to groups I want to know what is the most optimized way to create it between an ID and **then** the foreign keys, like that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PersonGroup
(
     Id Int DISTINCT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     PersonId Int, -- which is a foreign key to table Person
     GroupId Int   -- which is a foreign key to table Group
)
```

**OR** having the 2 foreign keys as a primary because no one can be 2 times in the same group anyway, like that :

```sql
CREATE TABLE PersonGroup
(
    PersonId Int NOT NULL, -- which is a foreign key to table Person
    GroupId Int NOT NULL,  -- which is a foreign key to table Group

    CONSTRAINT PK_PersonSgroup PRIMARY KEY (PersonId, GroupId)
)
```

What is the most optimized between those 2 tables for querying after (if there is more optimize).

Thank you to have read my post.

Comment: FYI, `Id Int DISTINCT NOT NULL Primary key,` isn't valid syntax. `DISTINCT` is an operator that goes in the `SELECT`, *not* in a columns definition, and a `PRIMARY KEY` already denotes that values in the column(s) must be distinct. Also, SQL Server/T-SQL uses parenthesis (`()`) not Braces (`{}`).

Comment: As for the question, the real question is can a Person belong to the same group twice; if they can, then option "1", if not option "2". There is very likely little to no difference in performance between the 2.

Comment: SQL uses the **round brackets** `( ... )` for its table definitions - not curly braces (`{ ... }`) - that's C# code ...

Answer (score 1):

The first solution (PK identity) is incomplete because you need to have an alternate (or surrogate) key (AK) compound of the two FK.

In the two possibilities, you must know that the order of the two FK in the PK or the AK is very important. This order must follow the usual querying way. So the questions are

- do you use first the group then the person in queries ?
- do you use first the personthen the group  in queries ?

Also you need an index on the second PK, not the first of the PK or AK compound of the two PK.

For me the best table will be:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonGroup
(
    PersonId Int NOT NULL REFERENCES Person (PersonId),
    GroupId Int NOT NULL REFERENCES Group (GroupId),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PersonSgroup PRIMARY KEY (PersonId, GroupId)
);
CREATE INDEX X_PersonGroup_FK_Group (GroupId);
```